# Impact of using .resx files to store multilingual content on the S.E.O

Tags: seo, asp.net, c#

Could anyone tell me whether google crawlers are capable of reading through the contents of a multilingual website which uses .resx files to dynamically switch languages, and if using resx have any impact on the SEO?
The way the project is organized is:

-it has a default culture hard coded into a main page and based on that ASP is serving the content from a default language .resx file.

-if the default culture of the project differs from the preferred users culture, then said culture is exchanged for the preferred users and the resources are drawn from appropriate .resx

-App_LocalResources contains resx with all the languages for each page separately as in mainpage.aspx.de.resx/mainpage.aspx.fr.resx anotherpage.aspx.de.resx/anotherpage.aspx.it.resx/anotherpage.aspx.resx (last one for default language) and so on

Comment: `.resx` files are an ASP thing, right?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx   I can't really tell from their documentation but it appears to be server side.   It says that ASP.NET is the thing that reads the file and derives the resources from it.   If that is the case Googlebot will never see the `.resx` files directly.  The worrying thing in that documentation is the statement "At run time, the browser indicates the user's preferred language" which probably means that it uses the `Accept-Language` header to decide.  That is decidedly **NOT** SEO friendly.

Comment: Can you edit the question with more information?   Are the resx files server side or client side?   Is the `Accept-Language` header used or is the language determined from the URL?

Comment: No i haven't used Accept-Language header

Comment: just in case anyone was ever wondering, Google crawlers have no problem with indexing content served from .resx files, so it IS SEO friendly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use Googlebot's fetch and render tool. It will show you exactly how Googlebot sees the webpage with your resx files and whether or not the resx script has an impact on Google's crawling service.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch